# Download CSV file from server to local direcory

Tags: php, jquery, csv

I have written a script in which I create and save a CSV file in a directory in my server. The CSV file contains attributes from a query.
The whole process is executed on a button click using Jquery and Ajax.

What I want to do now is to be able to save locally the generated CSV. I have found similar questions but I haven't found an answer on how to create a dialog box which will prompt the client to specify the location to save the file.

This is part of my Jquery code:

```
var nodeId = 'something';
var ajaxurl = 'requestsII/exportNodeData.php', // script to run
        data =  {nodeId:nodeId}; // data to pass
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {     
                //alert(response);

        });
```

And this is my PHP script:

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");  // EDITED

if ($db) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT kodpop AS "ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ ΚΟΜΒΟΥ",itemcode AS "ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ ΕΞΟΠΛΙΣΜΟΥ",temaxia AS "ΤΕΜΑΧΙΑ",status AS "STATUS" FROM bom WHERE type IN (:typeI, :typeII) AND kodpop = :nodeId');
    $stmt->execute(array('typeI' =>$typeI,'typeII' => $typeII,'nodeId' => $nodeId));

    #$results=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    #$json=json_encode($results);
    #echo($json);

    $filename = '/var/www/dkar/ruralBroadband/ruralApp/rural/csvExports/'.$nodeId.'.csv';

    $data = fopen($filename, 'w');

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        fputcsv($data, $row);
    }

    fclose($data);

}

echo($data); // EDITED
```

The question is how can I download locally the CSV file I create inside the PHP script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all I didn't use the above method and I did that, which works fine and its more straight forward:

```
var ajaxurl = 'exportNodeData.php', // script to run
                data =  {nodeId:nodeId}; // data to pass
                $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {     
                    document.location.href = 'https://www.ruralauditor.gr/csvExports/'+nodeId+'.zip';

                });
```

This is the ajax request, which I execute in order to create the CSV file (which is also zipped). I then use this line:

```
document.location.href = 'https://www.ruralauditor.gr/csvExports/'+nodeId+'.zip';
```

in order to force the download of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

echo "record1,record2,record3\n";
```

**Edit** :

Try This code

```
if ($db) 
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT kodpop AS "ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ ΚΟΜΒΟΥ",itemcode AS     "ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ ΕΞΟΠΛΙΣΜΟΥ",temaxia AS "ΤΕΜΑΧΙΑ",status AS "STATUS" FROM bom WHERE type  IN (:typeI, :typeII) AND kodpop = :nodeId');
$stmt->execute(array('typeI' =>$typeI,'typeII' => $typeII,'nodeId' => $nodeId));

#$results=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
#$json=json_encode($results);
#echo($json);

$filename = '/var/www/dkar/ruralBroadband/ruralApp/rural/csvExports/'.$nodeId.'.csv';



header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);  


while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($row);
}
}
```

Comment: Should I place this inside my php script?

Comment: you have to add header(first two header is sufficient) and echo your data.let me know if you get any further issue

Comment: Hmmm. I edited my php code. Added what you said but I get no prompt to download the csv file. What am I missing?

Comment: check the answer again.

Comment: This guy here opens the csv file: http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/creating-downloadable-csv-files/

Comment: Thanks for the effort man. I still can not make it work. Its weird. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I also faced the same issue . mentioned solution worked for me. try with another browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91700/discussion-between-rahul-agrawal-and-dkar).